# Generic type serializing Jackson xml

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml, jackson-databind

I am trying to serialize into XML this:

```
public class Box<T> {

    private T boxed;
}
```

with the next specific class type:

```
public class Person {
    // fields
}
```

but I get the next xml:

```
<box>
    <boxed>...</boxed>
</box>
```

instead of:

```
<box>
    <person>....</person>
</box>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Stuck here as well...

Comment: Sadly not @jam01, we had to create custom deserializers for this kind of hierarchy